# .spark views get copied to /bin/Views - why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, spark-view-engine

Building or publishing my ASP.MVC 2 application the .spark files in the View directories copied to /bin/Views/*.

This redundancy seems to be useless as the app runs fine on the server even if I delete the bin/Views directory.

Any idea how to prevent this behavior?

My files are tagged with the default build action "Content" and the View directories are Namespace providers as in the default MVC template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set views as content.

In order to do that - in solution explorer, click on view (or select multiple of them) and hit F4.

---

In properties, check `Copy to Output` prop. It should be false.

Comment: Thanks a lot! - sometimes one just doesn't see the obvious ;-)

Comment: I just had the same issue. :)